# get all outstanding user to user requests with only sender user_id and access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, apprequests

I tried $facebook->api('/me/apprequests/'); and that was blank even with 2 outstanding requests sent to 2 different friends.  Nothing shows on graph explorer either.

What I need is a way to get this information without knowing the request ID, because I need to add this information to my database after they send a user to user request, to prevent them from sending more than one request to a friend per day.  I know other apps do this, but I guess they aren't using FB.ui and probably record that info while sending the request?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get requests that user sent via [`apprequests`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests) connection of user object, only those user received.

> You can read the apprequests **sent to a user by your app** by issuing an `HTTP GET` request to `/USER_ID/apprequests` with user `access_token`.

You should store information about requests sent by application on your end if you need that info.

Comment: Example of how what? Store requests ids on your end? This is totally up to you and technology you use...